# Python: Find text with tags with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the tag `document` in my text and want to extract all texts between this text. A sample text of mine looks like this:

```
<document clueWebID="clueweb12-0710wb-90-29809">
  <sentences>
    <s relevant="true" sentenceID="0">
      <content>I&#65533;&#65533;m a Master&#65533;&#65533;s-level recreation therapist and CTRS.</content>
    </s>
    <s relevant="true" sentenceID="1">
      <content>The Individuals with Disabilities Education Act (IDEA) provides for therapeutic recreation for students that can benefit from recreation interventions.</content>
    </s>
    </sentences>
</document>
<document clueWebID="clueweb12-0710wb-90-29809">
  <sentences>
    <s relevant="true" sentenceID="4">
      <content>...because as soon as i researched ADHD&#65533;&#65533;my life fell into place&#65533;&#65533;and i now dont feel as detached/confused/alienated as i normally do ...is ther any1 on here from the UK?</content>
    </s>
    <s relevant="true" sentenceID="5">
      <content>...oh and has any1 got any info on Synaptol&#65533;&#65533;i am trying to get hold of some&#65533;&#65533;but its impossible in the UK&#65533;&#65533;and its really dear :/ ...i am starting college in sepember and really dont want to ruin it again!</content>
    </s>
    </sentences>
</document>
<document clueWebID="clueweb12-0102wb-15-11573">
  <sentences>
    <s relevant="true" sentenceID="6">
      <content>ADHD Medications Non-Drug ADHD Treatments Fine-Tuning Treatment Financing Treatment ADHD Symptoms &amp;amp; Statistics ADHD Basics Diagnosing ADHD Myths about ADHD About Learning Disabilities Meds at School</content>
    </s>
    </sentences>
</document>
```

I tried the following code:

```
re.findall('<document(.|\n)*?</document>',txt)
```

It extracts a list with the correct amount of elements (the number of elements are equal to the number of `document` tags). But the elements are empty and contain empty strings. 
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse something like this.  You should use an actual parser

Comment: yeah just use beautiful soup or lxml